# How do I make a batch file with a cycling password?

Tags: batch-file, windows-10

I want to make a Batch file that changes the password every time you open it.
I googled it but there are no results.
this is the code that I used to make a password lock.

```
@echo off
color a
:start
echo What is the password?
set /p word= :
if %word%==what goto right
if not %word%==what goto wrong
:wrong
cls
echo The password is wrong. Do you want to try again?
set /p pass= :
if %pass%==yes goto start
if %pass%==Yes goto start
if %pass%==YES goto start
if %pass%==y goto start
if %pass%==Y goto start
if not %pass%==yes goto end
if not %pass%==Yes goto end
if not %pass%==YES goto end
if not %pass%==y goto end
if not %pass%==Y goto end
:right
cls
echo The password is correct. Are you sure you want to proceed?
pause
```

Comment: 1, Try this: `if /I "%pass%"=="yes" goto start` and `if /I "%pass%"=="y" goto start` and `goto :EOF`. 2. Consider to use [`choice`](https://ss64.com/nt/choice.html) for Yes/No prompts...

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure how complicated of a password you are considering, but you can create a list of predefined words in a file, let's call it `words.txt` The words should be in list form:

```
passw1
guess
pseudo
daniel
susan
europe
etc.
```

Then your batch file:

```
@echo off
set /a rd=%random%%%20
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=]" %%a in ('type "words.txt" ^| find /v /n ""') do if [%rd%]==%%a]  echo %%b
pause
```

All this does is to add nmbers to each line, if the random number from `0` to `20` from the `random` variable matches any line number, it will use that particular word as a password. The above example simply uses maximum 20, but you can change that:

Then on your current code. No need to test each case variant of `yes` So you can pretty much just test using `if /i` for case insensitive match, but seeing as you only really case about the `y` in yes, you can test the first character only, so you can change your current code to this:

```
@echo off
color a
:start
set /p "word=What is the password?: "
if "%word%"=="what" goto right
:wrong
cls
echo The password is wrong. Do you want to try again?
set /p pass= :
if /i "%pass:~0,1%"=="y" goto start
goto :end
:right
cls
echo The password is correct. Are you sure you want to proceed?
pause
```

Also note that we do not need to test `if` and `if not` because we can just fall through to the next label if the `if` condition is not met.

PS!! I am not sure how you want someone to guess a random password though, if can become rather complicated.